# Stripe CardField in React Native not working in android - cannot focus it

Tags: android, react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe CardField component in a React Native app.
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native

On iOS everything is working fine,
but in *Android* I cannot make the app to focus the Stripe Component when I touch it...

If I add an `autofocus=true` to the cardfield it will focus on the field when the page load, and it will be working BUT if I touch outside the component will lose focus (as intended) but I will not be able to focus it again

this is my code

`parent component`

```
... other fields
   <View style={{width: '100%', height: 80}}>
    {/* */}
     <CardComponent />
   </View>
....
```

and my `card component` :

```
import { StripeContainer, CardField } from "@stripe/stripe-react-native";

const CardComponent = () => {
    return (
    <StripeContainer
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={false}
    >
        {/* tried to wrap it into <TouchableWithoutFeedback> */}
            <CardField
            postalCodeEnabled={false}
            placeholders={{
                number: '4242 4242 4242 4242',
            }}
           
            style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: 80,
                marginVertical: 30,
                marginTop: 12,
                zIndex: 999999,
            }}
            />

    </StripeContainer>
    );
}
export default CardComponent
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce on the official sample Stripe RN project via this screen:https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/master/example/src/screens/WebhookPaymentScreen.tsx